# How to pass the javascript substring output one page to another page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, substring

*I was trying to send the home page substring output to the second HTML page, but I could not*

*Could you help me get the output?*

*I use the codes below*

**HTML+JAVASCRPT+PYTHON_FLASK**

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
<input type="text" value="test" id="testInput" name="testInput"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="testCode">Click</button>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  const test = document.getElementById("testInput");
  var res = test.value.substr(0, 3);
  
  }
</script>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<p > Hello {{testInput}}<br></p>
</head>
</html>
```

**test.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():   
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      testInput =  request.form.get("testInput")
      res = request.form.get("res")
      testCode = request.form.get("testCode")
      test = request.form.get("test")
      return render_template("result.html",result=result,testInput=testInput,res=res,testCode=testCode, test=test)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? do you have a null value in `testCode`? what is it?

Comment: **yes..testCode is null value..When i put the string in the input box and click the button (home.html page), The substring(0,3) should be printed on result.html page**